# Telling the user that only whole numbers are allowed

Tags: c++, cin, cout

I am working on a project where the user needs to type a whole number. However, if the user types a decimal number, I have to alert the user that only whole numbers are allowed. How can I type that into C++.

Comment: `(int)num == num` True when num is a whole number

Comment: It would be helpful to show us what you tried.  If you're completely stumped, then at least describe the approach you expect to take.  For example, you could be expecting to have the user input a string, and then try converting it to an integer, and if it fails, then also try converting to a float, and if it succeeds, then report an error.  Or you could convert the input directly to a float and then just make a test to see if it is a round number.  "How can I type that into C++" sounds like you are very much a beginner.  Are you?  How much of this do you need help with?

Comment: Whole numbers are decimal numbers too

Comment: @Wyck I am a beginner. This is my first semester taking a computer science class. My project is pretty much done. I am just having some issues with some math calculations and this one question I asked. I am afraid to type the program here because my professor is very strict and believes that trying to find the answers online is cheating.

Comment: I don't mean to sound sarcastic, but have you tried asking your professor for help directly?  If your professor does not want you trying to find answers online then I'd feel weird about providing one.  How about capturing the user's input as a string and then searching it for a '.' (period / decimal point) character?  Would that approach work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `std::getline` function to read in an entire line. Then use the C standard library [`strtol`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) function to ensure the user typed in a valid whole number. It sets `errno` to a nonzero value to indicate overflow and `*endptr` to the first instance of an invalid character if an invalid character exists. If any of these indicators is set, we rerun the `do` loop, making the user re-enter the number until the data is valid

```
std::string line;
char *endptr;
long n;

do {
    std::cout << "Enter integer >= 0\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    n = strtol(line.c_str(), &endptr, 10);
} while ((errno != 0 && n == 0) || endptr == line.c_str() || *endptr != '\n' || n < 0);

// at this point, n is valid
```